# How to make a program user directly comes into when turns on PC?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I want to build a gadget with PC-boards like raspberry and Linux(or Windows) OS. And when user turns on the gadget sees my company name, and directly goes to my program and couldn't exit from that.something like ATM machines.
How can I do that?
What is this topic name and where can I find sources and guides?

Comment: This is generally known as a "kiosk" system - I've added a suitable tag for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hard-code your user-space process to run after bootup by updating the `init` script. You can run it as a `daemon` process and block all signals to it by the user. You can further disable other services and application processes like `login` process if you want the application to be accessed by everyone.

Link: [Creating a Kiosk with Linux](http://www.alandmoore.com/blog/2011/11/05/creating-a-kiosk-with-linux-and-x11-2011-edition/)

Comment: Your link was GREAAAT! Thanks a lot manav!

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you just configure the system to run your specialized program. This can be as simple as configuring (e.g. in some `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/rc.2/` ...) (or even replacing or enhancing) the [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) program, or configuring the startup of the [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server.

There are also several "kiosk oriented" Linux distributions. Details about configuration of the init process may be distribution specific. And [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) is now often a replacement of `init` and is configured specifically.

So you need first to choose some Linux distribution then dive into its documentation.

BTW, [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) knows about `@reboot` so can be a way to customize the startup procedure

You first should learn more about [Linux programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and its system administration (which is distribution specific). If you don't know Linux, I strongly suggest you to install Linux on your laptop and become familiar with it.

Maybe you should look into [raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/)

Comment: Thank you, I've worked with Ubuntu and did some image-processing programming on it. Is this distribution good for configuring or is better looking for "kiosk-oriented" distributions? 
The Ubuntu advantage is that many of PC-boards do support that, and Ubuntu is one of the best Linux distributions I think. 
But about my target not sure is it best choice or not?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the current issue (#93) of the  [fullcircle magazine](http://fullcirclemagazine.org/issue-93/) (as pdf or epub available). It contains an article about how to install a kiosk mode for ubuntu. It should be easily adoptable to your usecase (replace your app with firefox as mentioned in the article).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the founder of the opensource Webconverger Web kiosk project.

Debian based Webconverger uses the [inittab](https://github.com/Webconverger/webc/blob/master/etc/inittab#L60) to manage services. I highly recommend you work from the opensource Webconverger project and [do not roll you own kiosk](https://twitter.com/SwiftOnSecurity/status/519768632570564608).

The new version of Webconverger for Rpi2 and PCs will be using systemd exclusively.